# How to define a complex MongoDb document Id?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've a situation where I want to store count of messages of a particular user in a chat in a particular day.
To make the Id unique, I thought I should combine these ids together and it became ~20 characters length consisted of `ChatId` + `DDMMYY` + `UserId`

```
public class UserContributions
{
    [BsonId]
    public string ChatIdDateUserId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    // the rest
}
```

But I guess an ID with this length is not good regarding performance. Is that How I should make a complex ID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length should not be too much of a problem. Furthermore, you can have a compound `_id`

```
{
  _id:{
    ChatID: "someId",
    Date: ISODate("2017-10-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
    UserID: "someUID"
  }
}
```

Some notes first: Do ***NOT*** use strings to denote a date. First of all, ISODates are stored as 64bit unsigned integer. While with a date stored as 6 characters, you save some space, but you loose all capabilities for [date operations in aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) as well as [normal date comparisons](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query-comparison/). *Bad* idea.

Second, your model is prone to collision. The same user at the same date could only post one message to a specific chat. The second message of the day would have *exactly* the same values and hence would violate the constraint of uniqueness. So you actually have to use the full ISODate, down to the millisecond.
And still then, there is a small chance of collision (say you have a date generated on two application servers which are slightly of time wise). There is a reason why [there is an additional counter in ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

Here is how I would model it

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  ChatId: "someChat",
  UserId: "someUser"
}
```

Reason: the ObjectId contains a timestamp by which you can query (I do not know C# well enough to give an example, hence I will make this a wiki answer to give others the opportunity to do so), eliminates unneeded complexity and with indices on both `ChatId` and `UserId` it is fast enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Markus. (There should be only one message for a user in one day by design. This document contains some counters and other activity info for that particular day)

Comment: @Blendster: This sounds more like the job of an aggregation, no?